# How do I get cabal gloss working on IOS el Capitan?

Tags: haskell, cabal, gloss

After I installed cabal and try to run my (very basic) haskell code in which include import Graphics.Gloss

I get an error message `Could not find module ‘Graphics.Gloss’`.
 Can´t figure out why as I seem to have installed it the correct way...

Can anyone help me in this!!

Comment: "Very basic" Haskell program don't involve Graphics :) Did you executed `cabal update` to get the latest index of packages? Did you add the dependency `gloss` to your .cabal file? Where did you get the error message, I guess from an editor? Did you execute `cabal install --only-denepdencies` and by doing so install all the dependencies into the sandbox or globally? You may read [the manual](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/) again for detailed explanation.

Comment: Please show the line you used to install gloss.  Please show what you typed and the full error message that you showed us a fragment of.  Without these we are stuck in mind-reader mode.

Answer (score 1):

The first steps on this website shows you, how you can run Haskell program with gloss http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/haskell/haskell-gloss/